# KOL application's main icon

Tags: delphi, kol

I want to use [KOL](http://kolmck.net/) to make very small Exe.

Everything is seems to be ok, but I don't know how to set the main icon of the application (in the taskbar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an icon resource to your project with the icon name being `MAINICON`.

So, in your .rc file you have this:

```
MAINICON ICON "MyAppIcon.ico"
```

And in the .dpr file compile and link the resource like this:

```
{$R 'MyApp.res' 'MyApp.rc'}
```

If you have an older version of Delphi that won't accept this syntax for `$R` then you'll need to compile the resource manually and link it like so:

```
{$R 'MyApp.res'}
```

---

For example, this .dpr file:

```
uses
  KOL;

{$R 'MyApp.res'}

var
  Form: PControl;

begin
  Form := NewForm(nil, 'My form');
  Run(Form);
end.
```

is all you need to create an app with a main form having an icon, and that icon being shown on the task bar.

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

Note that some of the KOL demo projects have code like this:

```
Form.Icon := THandle(-1);
```

which naturally interferes with any attempts to impose an icon. Clearly you'll need to remove any such code. I struggled with this a little whilst answering this question (my first ever KOL project FWIW) and wonder if you might have the same problem.

Comment: Since an icon with the name "MAINICON" is exactly what the IDE will put in the resource file for you, it sounds like all you really need to do with KOL is make sure the `$R` directive is present in your project file, the same as with any other Delphi project. Then the icon-configuration part of the project-option dialog will work the same as it always has.

Comment: @Rob Yes, that will work as well. I guess that if you are using KOL, you are quite likely to be a little picky about what is linked to your app. Plus, I always link my own .res files because I don't like how the IDE does it.

Comment: Also note that `SMALLEST_CODE` should not have been defined for {$R  ...} to work. Otherwise load and set your icon yourself.